# How to place 3 blocks (span, span, input) in one line with vertical align?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have html something like this http://jsfiddle.net/nLt9unxa/5/ and I want to place 3 block `.number__label`, `.text__label`, and `.from__input` in one line. `.form__input` must be align to the right side of form and all 3 elements must be vertical align in one line. How to do this? And I don't want use `display: table-cell`

And also if you know very good tutorial or book about alignment, where described all possible alignment and receipts how to do it, like cheatsheet, please share link.

Comment: you forgot to put : after max-width in .number__label

Comment: if you just mean to display inline, than yes there is a typo (missing : ).  If you want to vertically align, than use CSS property "vertical-align".  More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to put **`:`** after `max-width and min-width` in `.number__label`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nLt9unxa/8/)

```
.number__label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: solid 1px;
    max-width:20%;
    min-width:20%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use vertical-align: middle (or top, or bottom).  Here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/1ddewjxd/

```
.class
{  
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

to align elements to right set the parent element to text-align: right, and the child elements to text-align: left.  You could also float: right, but that can complicate things.

```
.item__label {
    text-align: right;
}
.number__label, text__label, form__input {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: And like @himanshu said, you forgot the : after max-width and min-width.  I also just replaced those with width: 20% to shorten the code.

Comment: Almost perfect, but about alignment to the right side of form, I mean only `.form__input` element must be alignment, not text.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I explained my thoughts wrong. I want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/1ddewjxd/2/ but `float: right` ruined `vertical-alignment`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/osbka2wr/ this will align them all to the top... I added an element with clear: both in the html.  Do you need middle alignment?  There are ways to make this work

Comment: If you are trying to vertical align and float together, this article will help:  http://www.markwyner.com/post/20779940709/vertically-align-floated-elements-with-css  good luck!

Comment: From article http://jsfiddle.net/osbka2wr/4/ How to know right value for negative `margin-top` property to place `.form__input` right in the middle?

Comment: This sounds like you may want to backtrack a bit... centering a floated element seems real tricky, in addition to the other code.  You may want to set those 3 elements to add to 100% rather than 90%.  You'll need to normalize CSS though.  This is the closest I can come, but I still see margin/padding that is throwing off the percents somehow:  http://jsfiddle.net/yrga2hd9/

Answer (score 0):

Run this code snippet to check whether all your requirements are done or not? also check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pradyumnaswain/nLt9unxa/6/)
Check [CSS Layout](http://learnlayout.com/) or learn from [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp)

```css
form {
    width:70%;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    font-size: 20px;

}
.itme__label {
    display: block;
    
}
.form__item {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}

.number__label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: solid 1px;
    max-width 20%;
    min-width 20%;
}
.text__label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #888888;
    max-width: 50%;
}
.form__input {
    display: block;
    min-width: 20%;
    max-width: 20%;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-left:120px;
  
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="form__item">
        <p>
            <label class="item__label">
                <span class="number__label">
                01 12 31 23  123 2452 34534 5345
                </span>
                <span class="text__label">
                text label long long long very long long for two or more lines ong very long long for two or more linesong very long long for two or more lines
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form__input" value="input text">
                
                </input>
            </label>
        </p>
        <div class="errors">
            <p class="error">
            some error
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```